# How to get all text from qlineedit

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I just want to know how to store all the values from all the qline edit text after clicking the 'Execute the values' button, as of now, only the recent value it takes,
How to iterate through all inputs and take it all individual variables:

```
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.title = 'Sample Dynamic LineEdit'
    self.left = 150
    self.top = 150
    self.width = 400
    self.height = 500
    self.i = 40
    self.j = 80
    self.counter = 1
    self.initUI()

def initUI(self):
    self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
    self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

    # Create textbox
    # self.textbox = QLineEdit(self)
    # self.textbox.move(20, 20)
    # self.textbox.resize(280, 40)

    # Create a button in the window
    self.button = QPushButton('Add Line Edit', self)

    # connect button to function on_click
    self.button.clicked.connect(self.on_click)
    self.show()
    pybutton = QPushButton('Execute the entered values', self)
    pybutton.clicked.connect(self.text_click)
    pybutton.resize(160, 35)
    pybutton.move(150, 0)
    pybutton.show()

@pyqtSlot()
def on_click(self):
    # this creates a new field and label everytime the button is clicked
    self.textbox = QLineEdit(self)
    self.textbox2 = QLineEdit(self)

    self.label = QLabel(self)
    self.label.setText(str(self.counter))
    self.label.move(5, self.i)
    self.button.move(20, self.j)
    self.textbox.move(20, self.i)
    self.textbox.resize(160, 40)
    self.textbox2.move(250, self.i)
    self.textbox2.resize(160, 40)

    # dynamic object names
    self.textbox.setObjectName("text" + str(self.counter))
    self.textbox.show()
    self.textbox2.show()
    self.label.show()
    self.i += 40
    self.j += 40
    self.counter += 1
    print(self.textbox.objectName())

def text_click(self):
    first = self.textbox.text()
    
    print('Your name: ' + first)
    second = self.textbox2.text()
    print('Your name: ' + second)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could give a name to every QLineEdit and then use `findChild` to access them:

```
    ...
    # dynamic object names
    self.textbox.setObjectName("text_" + str(self.counter))
    self.textbox2.setObjectName("text2_" + str(self.counter))
    ...

def text_click(self):
    for i in range(1, self.counter):
        first = self.findChild(QLineEdit, "text_" + str(i)).text()

        print('Your name: ' + first)
        second = self.findChild(QLineEdit, "text2_" + str(i)).text()
        print('Your name: ' + second)
```

But IMHO it is more simple to just add the QLineEdit objects to plain lists:

```
...
    self.counter = 1
    self.textboxes = []
    self.textboxes2 = []
    self.initUI()
...
@Slot()
def on_click(self):
    # this creates a new field and label everytime the button is clicked
    textbox = QLineEdit(self)
    textbox2 = QLineEdit(self)
    self.textboxes.append(textbox)
    self.textboxes2.append(textbox2)

    label = QLabel(self)
    label.setText(str(self.counter))
    label.move(5, self.i)
    self.button.move(20, self.j)
    textbox.move(20, self.i)
    textbox.resize(160, 40)
    textbox2.move(250, self.i)
    textbox2.resize(160, 40)

    # dynamic object names
    textbox.setObjectName("text_" + str(self.counter))
    textbox2.setObjectName("text2_" + str(self.counter))
    textbox.show()
    textbox2.show()
    label.show()
    self.i += 40
    self.j += 40
    self.counter += 1
    print(textbox.objectName())

def text_click(self):
    for i in range(self.counter - 1):
        first = self.textboxes[i].text()

        print('Your name: ' + first)
        second = self.textboxes2[i].text()
        print('Your name: ' + second)
...
```

In Python, storing an object in a list is cheap, because the list will only contain a reference to the object. The only downside here is that the Qt objects are internally C++ objects that can be destroyed independently of their Python reference. So you have to take care of not using them once they are destroyed.

Comment: Hi @Serge Ballesta, This really helped me alot, Thank you for your support Serge. Would u suggest me to go thru qt designer and then convert to py script for further developments, or it is better to develop thru coding script itself.

Comment: Hi @Serge Ballesta,

How Do I create a button, so that after entering all the values in this lineedit, I need a button which will clear all the values..

Comment: @NishadNazar: designer is a nice tool, and should be used for any static interface design, because you immediately see how the interface will look like. For a run-time dynamic interface, it can still be used for the initial design. And do not forget *layouts* which give nice redimensionable interfaces. But if you really need to add child widgets at run time, you will only be able to use direct code for that part.

Comment: @NishadNazar: You already know how to create a widget at run time and give it a name. Here, you could create a new QPushButton per line and connect them all to the same slot in your main widget (BTW naming a widget *app* is a weird convention and will amaze future readers...). Then in that slot, you will use `sender` to identify the clicked button, and act accordingly on the relevant QLineEdit widgets.

Comment: Sure I'll try this. Thank you Serge